# Rerequest does not work with passport-facebook-token

Tags: node.js, facebook, email, authorization, passport.js

I need emails from facebook for my app to work correctly. However, the user has an option of turning off email from the auth screen. When that happens I get an empty emails field like this

```
    "emails":[{"value":""}]
```

Here's my original request

```
passport.authenticate('facebook-token', { scope :['email'] }, function(err, profile) {
    fbhandler(req, res, err, profile);
})(req, res);
```

and here's where I handle the returned values

```
        passport.use(new FacebookTokenStrategy({
                clientID:       config.facebookAuth.clientID,
                clientSecret:   config.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
            profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'emails', 'name']
            }, 

            function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
                console.log ("##### %j", profile);
                var id = profile.id,
                    email = profile.emails[0].value,
                    methodId = 2;
                if (email == "") {
                    return done(res.json({
                        errors: "Facebook",
                    }));
                }
        .. Do normal stuff.
}
```

and the fbhandler

```
var fbhandler = function(req, res, err, profile) {
       console.log("###### %j"  ,profile);
       if (!profile) {
          console.log("reauth####");
          passport.authenticate('facebook-token', { authType: 'rerequest', scope :['email'] }, function(err, profile) {
                      //Do normal stuff
                  })(req, res);

       } else {
       //do normal stuff
       }
    }
```

The rerequest never puts up the auth screen again (actually it just flashes for a second) and it returns empty emails once again.

This seems to be a passport issue and not a FB rerequest issue since I was able to do this successfully with FB JS SDK. You can view this at www.kavyavidya.us (click on fb login at the bottom, edit info in the auth screen and uncheck email address) Notice how it pops up the email address auth screen once again with no option to turn it off.

How can I ensure that the auth screen will popup again for email?

Comment: Your example is not actually testable, it gives an error message only: _“App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.”_

Comment: Sorry about that. I was using a test app ID. Updated to the live one. Please check now

Comment: That's true that `rerequest` doesn't work in that plugin. And it hasn't been working for more than two years now. And maintainer doesn't seem to bother.